# How to get Tip-of-tree version of Chrome Debugger in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing a Chrome Extension which utilizes the [Chrome Debugger protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).

To do this, I call `chrome.debugger.attach(Debuggee d, string requiredVersion)` ([documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger#method-attach)).

My question is about the **requiredVersion** param. According to the docs, you specify a version number of the protocol to use, and [this link](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) contains possible versions you can use. So on that link, you see possible versions: 1.2, 1.3, and tip-of-tree.

I can pass in "1.2" or "1.3" and the call to `chrome.debugger.attach` succeeds, however does anyone know what string I pass in to use the tip-of-tree version? It doesn't correspond to any numbered version. Or is using tip-of-tree not possible?

Comment: ToT may be served to users of Canary/dev versions of Chrome even if you specify "1.3". Anyway, there's [no special value](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/devtools/devtools_agent_host_impl.cc?type=cs&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=86).

Comment: I see. Does this mean that ToT is only available on Canary/dev versions of Chrome? I was unable to access some of the features marked as "Experimental" when writing the Chrome extension; I guess this was because I was using the stable version of Chrome?

Comment: Stable doesn't include experimental extension APIs so it's kinda expected the same applies here.

Comment: Understood, thanks.